# How to create simple Horizontal Timeline

Tags: html, css

I can't make these with HTML + CSS:
[image: Sample]

I try everything...with :before, with: after, but i really can't make it.
I make a JsFiddle demo.
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hf19qbg2/12/)
How can i make this? Do you have idea?

Other question: This can be resonsive too? (I think not...:()

Code (CSS):

```
    .container {
  width:1025px;
  display:block;
  height:400px;
}
.container:before{
  content:'';
  width:1025px;
  height:15px;
  background-color:blue;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:20%;
}

.container div{
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  background-size: 22px 22px;
  padding-left:22px;

}

.container div.span:before{
  content:'';
   background:url('http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons/firey-orange-jelly-icons-alphanumeric/070242-firey-orange-jelly-icon-alphanumeric-information3-sc49.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:left;
  display:block;
  width:22px;
  height:22px;
      background-size: contain;
}

.container div.down:after{
  content:'';
   background:url('http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons/firey-orange-jelly-icons-alphanumeric/070242-firey-orange-jelly-icon-alphanumeric-information3-sc49.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:left;
  display:block;
  width:22px;
  height:22px;
      background-size: contain;
}
```

Code(HTML):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="span">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="down">Dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="span">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="down">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  <div class="span">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="down">Lorem</div>
  <div class="span">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="down">Lorem</div>
  <div class="span">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="down">Lorem ipsum</div>
  <div class="span">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div class="down">Lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Responsive? [demo of  "responsive timeline css"](https://codyhouse.co/demo/vertical-timeline/index.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A description of the specifics would take a while so I'll just make a brief demo of *one* method which would seem to be something along the lines of what you seem to be after.

The code id quite inefficient (and non-responsive at the moment) but I hope the basics are enough to see you along the way.

```css
.timeline {
  height: 250px;
  margin: 1em;
  line-height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.timeline:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 10%;
  height: 26px;
  margin-top: -13px;
  background: red;
}
.event {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.detail {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: 100%;
}
.event:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -3px;
  width: 6px;
  background: green;
  height: 50px;
}
.event.up:before {
  top: -100%;
}
.event.down:before {
  top: 100%;
}
.up .detail {
  top: -50px;
}
.down .detail {
  bottom: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="event up">
    <div class="detail">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="event down">
    <div class="detail">lorem</div>
  </div>
  <div class="event up">
    <div class="detail">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) You are awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/hf19qbg2/16/

**Preview**
[image]

```
.container {
  width:80%;
  display:block;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  margin: 50px 0;
  height: 5px;
}

.top,
.bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.bottom {
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.top .top-element,
.bottom .bottom-element {
  padding: 0 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.top-element:before,
.bottom-element:before {
  content: "I";
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #C33900;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.top-element:before {
  bottom: -63px;
}

.bottom-element:before {
  top: -63px;
}

.top-element:after,
.bottom-element:after {
  content: "";
  height: 50px;
  width: 2px;
  background: #8ACCC6;
  position: absolute;
}

.top-element:after {
  left: 10px;
  bottom: -40px;
}

.bottom-element:after {
  left: 10px;
  top: -40px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="top">
    <div class="top-element">Lorem top 1</div>
    <div class="top-element">Lorem top 2</div>
    <div class="top-element">Lorem top 3</div>
    <div class="top-element">Lorem top 4</div>
  </div>

    <div class="line"></div>

  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="bottom-element">Lorem bottom 1</div>
    <div class="bottom-element">Lorem bottom 2</div>
    <div class="bottom-element">Lorem bottom 3</div>
    <div class="bottom-element">Lorem bottom 4</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you :) You helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Find an elegant and simple example that I have created [HERE](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/OMLzYj?editors=110). I have used `ul` and `li` tags to do the job quicker. To change the number of items, you just need to deal with the number of `li` tags you have.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>i</li>
    <li>i</li>
    <li>i</li>
    <li>i</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
  background: #0048FF;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

li {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 5px 11px;
  top: -3px;
  background: #e59741; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #e59741 21%, #c22d0b 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #e59741 21%,#c22d0b 100%); /*     Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg,  #e59741 21%,#c22d0b 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e59741', endColorstr='#c22d0b',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient     */
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  font-size:14px;
}
li:nth-child(2n+1):after {
  content:"\00a0\00a0number1\00a0number3";
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
  color: black;
  top: -50px;
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 12px;
  border-left: 2px solid #9CD4CF;
}

li:nth-child(2n):after {
  content: "\00a0\00a0number1\00a0number2";
  position: absolute;
  padding: 30px 0 0px 0;
  color: black;
  top: 25px;
  left: 12px;
  border-left: 2px solid #9CD4CF;
}
```